# Manipulando String em Java

Tags: java, string

Tenho um texto dentro de uma String.
Irei percorrer essa String. Ao percorre-la preciso pegar cada palavra que contém nela.
Pensei em usar `string.split(" ");` mas eu preciso tratar "." ";" "," ":" "!" "?" entre outros casos.
Como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Você quer fazer split por esses caracteres, ou remover esses caráteres da frase?

Comment: @Fernando eu tenho que pegar palavra por palavra, sendo o ultimo caracter da substring a ultima letra da palavra.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Você pode usar Regex. Exemplo:

```
public class TesteRegex {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String frase = "Várias palavras em uma só String.\n"
                + "Ignorando pontos; Ponto-e-vírgula; Traços. E números 0132.";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Zà-úÀ-Ú]+");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(frase);
        int i = 1;
        while(m.find()) {
            System.out.println("Palavra " + i + ": " + m.group());
            i++;
        }
        System.out.println("Frase completa: " + frase);
    }
}
```

Resultado:

> Palavra 1: Várias
>   Palavra 2: palavras
>   Palavra 3: em
>   Palavra 4: uma
>   Palavra 5: só
>   Palavra 6: String
>   Palavra 7: Ignorando
>   Palavra 8: pontos
>   Palavra 9: Ponto
>   Palavra 10: e
>   Palavra 11: vírgula
>   Palavra 12: Traços
>   Palavra 13: E
>   Palavra 14: números
>   Frase completa: Várias palavras em uma só String.
>   Ignorando pontos; Ponto-e-vírgula; Traços. E números 0132.

O pattern que eu utilizei `[a-zA-Zà-úÀ-Ú]+` informa que é para incluir tudo que vai de `a` até `z` e tudo que vai de `à` até `ú`, para ambos os casos tanto maiúsculos como minúsculos. O sinal de `+` indica para pegar grupos ao invés de caracteres isolados.

Consequentemente todo o restante será ignorado, isso inclui todos os espaços, caracteres especiais e números, como pode ver no exemplo acima.

Olhando a [lista de caracteres Unicode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_script_in_Unicode) podemos ver que a faixa que vai de `à` até `ú` pega alguns caracteres que podem ser considerados indesejáveis, como por exemplo o `æ`, `å`, `÷` e o `ø`. Veja os trechos completos:

> **De À a Ú**: À   Á   Â   Ã   Ä   Å   Æ   Ç   È   É   Ê   Ë   Ì   Í   Î   Ï   Ð   Ñ   Ò   Ó   Ô   Õ   Ö   ×   Ø   Ù   Ú
>
> **De à a ú**: à   á   â   ã   ä   å   æ   ç   è   é   ê   ë   ì   í   î   ï   ð   ñ   ò   ó   ô   õ   ö   ÷   ø   ù   ú

Caso esteja pegando arquivos de variadas fontes você pode se deparar com eles em determinados momentos, caso esteja lendo através de um TextField que o usuário está digitando eu diria que é desnecessário eliminar tais caracteres da lista pois dificilmente alguém vai digitar um `Å` no meio de um texto, nosso teclado nem está preparado para isso (eu mesmo tive que copiar e colar).

Mas caso prefira, pode usar um pattern mais específico que aceita apenas os caracteres que usamos em nosso alfabeto, que seria esse: `[a-zA-ZàáâãçèéêìíòóõùúÀÁÂÃÇÈÉÊÌÍÎÒÓÔÕÙÚ]+`

Repare que o sinal de `-` indica faixas de valores, logo `à-ú` aceita tudo que vai de `à` até `ú`, e no pattern acima eu não utilizei a faixa de valores para os caracteres acentuados, eu especifiquei um a um quais são esses caracteres que devem ser aceitos. Para os não acentuados eu mantive o `a-zA-Z`, pois não existe nenhum caractere indesejado no meio deles.

Comment: com esse pattern o 'ç' está incluido?

Comment: @Pacíficão sim senhor! O `à` seria o primeiro de todos os caracteres "acentuados", e o `ú` é o último, isso quer dizer que o `ç` está incluso.

Comment: @Pacíficão pus a lista completa dos caracteres que vão de `à` a `ú` e criei um pattern que elimina alguns caracteres que podem ser considerados indesejáveis em sua aplicação. Como não sei de onde você está lendo esses caracteres pode ser uma boa ideia utilizá-lo, apesar do `à-ú` já ser bem eficiente para a maioria das situações.

Comment: deu certo.. alterei o pattern que você mudou -----mais uma vez, muito obrigado! acho que eh a milessima vez q vc me salva :D

Comment: Acho que essa regex poderia ser substituida por `"[\\p{L}]+"` não poderia?

Comment: @RodrigoSasaki antes de mais nada queria dizer que tive que pesquisar para te responder. De acordo com [esse site](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html), o pattern `[\\p{L}]+` aceita todas as letras do Unicode. Não tenho certeza de quais são todas as letras, mas sei que esse pattern é muito mais abrangente que os dois que eu inclui na minha resposta. Fiz alguns testes e percebi que ele aceitou inúmeros diferentes caracteres, como por exemplo: `Ω`. Portanto, acredito que o melhor é fazer um pattern comprido mas que garante o bom funcionamento do programa do AP.

Comment: @Math entendi. Realmente é mais abrangente do que eu imaginava. Ótima resposta e solução!

Comment: @Math eu preciso que reconhecer quando há \n na string. Como posso fazer isso? Eu utilizo o pattern tbm?

Comment: @Pacíficão depende, se eu entendi bem basta você colocar um `\n` dentro do `[` e `]`. Pode ser por exemplo depois do `Ú`. Veja se é isso que precisa, se não for explique o que aconteceu e como precisa que seja.

Comment: @Math quando coloco \n depois do Ú ele da erro na execução: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 65514

Comment: @Pacíficão você tem certeza que essa é motivo pelo qual ocorre o Exception? Eu fiz alguns testes aqui e rodou normal. Vejo no stack trace inteiro o que ocasionou isso, pois me soou estranho. E tb se for o caso explique um pouco melhor a aplicação do seu programa, pois pelo que eu entendi você quer aceitar o \n no seu texto de entrada, mas isso causa um efeito que não tenho certeza que seja o desejável, você estará armazenando um \n na sua String, enquanto você poderia simplesmente descartá-lo.

Comment: @Math funfou \o/

Answer (score 3):

Você pode utilizar expressão regular para esse fim.

**Split**

O método `split` da `String` Java aceita expressão regular. Veja [aqui na documentação](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)).

Algo assim: `[.;,:!?]` (é um grupo de caracteres que deseja filtrar).

Isso irá fazer um split pelos caracteres informados, retornando um Array.

Em Java seria algo assim:

```java
String str = "Eu sei? que nada, sei, mais uns .'s e umas ,'s";
String[] result = str.split("[.;,:!?]");
for (String r : result) {
    System.out.println(r.toString());       
}
```

A saída seria assim:

```
Eu sei
 que nada
 sei
 mais uns 
's e umas 
's
```

**Replace**

Você também pode fazer um `replace` nos caracteres indesejados. O método `replaceAll` da String do java também aceita expressão regular, veja [aqui na documentação](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)).

Seria algo assim:

```java
String result2 = str.replaceAll("[.;,:!?]", "");
System.out.println(result2);
```

A saída seria assim:

```
Eu sei que nada sei mais uns 's e umas 's
```

> Pelo que entendi é algo assim que você procura. Certo?
>
> Veja se isso lhe atende.

Comment: eu não posso substituir principalmente os pontos de final de frase '!' '.' '?' pois depois eu vou precisar distinguir frases diferentes. Não posso alterar o texto.

Comment: @Pacíficão, não entendi, você não quer remover os `'!' '.' '?'`? Mas quer fazer split por eles? Explique melhor. Se possível de exemplos.