# Pegar apenas o primeiro nome, após espaço usando Java

Tags: java, regex

Boa tarde.

Tenho a seguinte String:

> "Carlos Ferreira da Silva"

Eu queria pegar apenas o primeiro nome e ignorar  resto após o "espaço".

Usando expressões regulares, como eu poderia fazer isso?

Comment: Precisa mesmo de regex? Da pra fazer isso sem usar regex e é bem mais simples.

Comment: @diegofm concordo...

Comment: Desculpe por comentar em uma pergunta respondida, mas você pode fazer de forma bem mais simples através do método `split("")`, da classe `String`. Basta apenas escrever essa linha: `String primeiroNome = "Carlos Ferreira da Silva".split(" ")[0];`. O método `split(" ")` separa em um array de `String`s uma `String` delimitada pelo caractere passado como parâmetro. No nosso caso o espaço. Já no retorno desse método informamos que queremos a primeira posição através de `[0]` e pronto. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basta você usar o padrão `\\S+`

Exemplo:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
      String linha = "João Ferreira da Silva";
      String pattern = "\\S+";

      Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
      Matcher m = r.matcher(linha);
      if (m.find( )) {
        System.out.println(m.group(0) );
      }
    }
}
```

Saída:

> João

Veja no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/ZWmZ3B).

De acordo com a [documentação](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html), o `\\S` faz o match com caracteres que não sejam espaços e o `+` serve para ir pegando os caracteres até que a condição não seja mais satisfeita.

Comment: O `\\w` faz match com caracteres acentuados?

Comment: @RômuloGabrielRodrigues não, me atentei ao exemplo e não pensei nessa condição

Comment: Acabei me lembrando de um exemplo parecido nessa questão http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/27846/3117

Comment: Tentei usando "José" e realmente não faz com caracteres acentuados. Mas a dica tá excelente, bem enxuto o código.

Comment: @AmandaRJ mudei o exemplo, acho que o `\\S+` atende melhor a questão

Comment: @Math obrigada. Ficou perfeito para oque eu preciso. Muito obrigada!!!

Comment: Você poderia manter o mesmo código e ter mudado o *pattern* para `\\p{L}+` ou `\\p{IsLatin}+`.

Comment: @FelipeMarinho poisé, tem várias formas de fazer, como a pergunta não específica uma forma clara acaba dando margem para várias respostas, como acredito que é uma aplicação simples e talvez até de forma didática acho que não terão outros charsets no texto acho que o \\S deve atender :) mas realmente a sua sugestão é boa para situações reais

Answer (score 1):

Usando expressões regulares você pode pegar o primeiro nome com a regex `^([a-zA-ZÈ-Úè-ú]+)\s` podemos pegar apenas o primeiro nome:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Regex {

   public static void main( String args[] ) {
      // String com texto a ser verificado
      String texto = "André Carlos Ferreira da Silva";
      // Expressão regular a ser usada
      String pattern = "^([a-zA-ZÈ-Úè-ú]+)\\s";
      // Inicialização de RegExp Pattern
      Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
      // Inicialização do verificador de pattern em texto
      Matcher m = r.matcher(texto);

      // Se (matcher encontrou regexp na string)
      if (m.find()) {
         // escreva o grupo encontrado
         System.out.println("Olá, " + m.group(0) );
      } else {
         // mensagem de erro
         System.out.println("Você não tem mais de um nome?");
      }
   }
}
```

Você pode testar expressões regulares facilmente utilizando o [Regex101](https://regex101.com/), esta expressão está registrada em https://regex101.com/r/lVvPcx/1

[Demonstração](https://ideone.com/iyJTl6)